# Selenium find element by xpath not working

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

So to find a word in a certain page i decided to do this:

```
    bodies = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[self::span or self::strong or self::b or self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or self::h6 or self::p]')
    for i in bodies:
        bodytext = i.text
        if "description" in bodytext or "Description" in bodytext:
            print("found")
            print(i.text)
```

I believe the code itself is fine, but ultimately I get nothing. To be honest I am not sure what is happening, it just seems like it doesn't work.
Here is an example of what [website](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Mummy-Sleeping-Bag-5F-15C-Camping-Hiking-With-Carrying-Case-Brand-New/310910954969?epid=22003301214&hash=item4863bcadd9:g:u08AAOSwhqhaA6eT) it would be ran on.  Here is some of the page source:

```
<h2>product description</h2>
```

EDIT: It may be because the element is not in view, but I have tried to fix it with that in mind. Still, no luck.

Comment: I´m no expert in Xpath but it looked wrong to me.

I tested the Xpath with this website http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath against the xml of the website in your question and it outputs error, probably thats why your code doesn´t output anything.

Check your Xpath or first just try to get one element, if it works try to add another, until you get all you want.

Comment: yeah i know it looks strange, but it works when i try: `if "the" in bodytext:`

Answer (score 2):

Inspect the element and check if its inside the iframe,

if it does, you need switch to the frame first

```
driver.switch_to_frame(frame_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try waiting for a few ms to ensure the page has rendered and the expected element is visible with:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

Alternatively, try using IDs or custom data attributes to target the elements instead of xpath. Something like `find_by_css_selector('.my_class')` may work better.